# Device is not subscribing in oOneSignal throwing No Push Token error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to for push notifications for android in unity through OneSignal.
Iam following this document https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk-setup. I have imported the package and kept my app Id from one signal and run the code.

The user added but not had subscribed.There I am getting error No Push Token , is there any thing to add more than that document.
1.Created a project in fire base .
2.Created a project with unity SDK in oneSingal and added FireBase keys.
3.Added the following code to the first scene start().

```
void Start()
    {

        OneSignal.StartInit("App ID from oneSignal.")
         .HandleNotificationReceived(HandleNotificationReceived)
         //.InFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
         .EndInit();
```

And executed the code. While checking the users in ONeSignal I found them as following.

[image]